# Can I use the octopress image tag with jekyll-assets asset_path?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid, octopress

If it's possible, I'd like to use the [Octopress image tag](http://octopress.org/docs/plugins/image-tag/) on images that are served using [jekyll-assets](https://github.com/ixti/jekyll-assets/).

This works

```
<img src="{% asset_path image.jpg %}" alt="foo" />
```

but I'd prefer something like this

```
{% img asset_path image.jpg 'foo' %}
```

which gives an error:

```
Error processing input, expected syntax: {% img [class name(s)] [http[s]:/]/path/to/image [width [height]] [title text | “title text” [“alt text”]] %}
```

Is there a way to get the syntax right, passing the result of `asset_path` to `img`? I expect the answer is obvious, but I'm new to Liquid and Jekyll.

I am using the latest stable release of octopress, which depends on jekyll 0.12.1. I am using jekyll-assets 0.4.2, which is the latest version that supports jekyll < 1.0.

Comment: Sure, that works, but the goal was to use ``asset_path``, which is a function.

Comment: Ah, okay.  Sorry.  I'll delete my previous comment.

Comment: Did you try "asset_path("image.jpg")" ?